# How to burn Mac OSX .iso to DL-DVD on Windows 7 PC?

Tags: macos, iso-image, dvd-burning

I've made a backup ISO of my Mac OSX DVD. I'm trying to burn that same ISO back onto a Dual Layer DVD (the image size is just north of 7gb).

I created a DVD using Windows 7 image burning software, however, the Mac cannot boot using the DVD. Is there a specific software package or set of steps I need to take to recreate my backup image to work on the mac using a PC to burn the ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you backed up the "files" on the disk... but did not backup the disk.  DVDs have some special bits that need to be set in the image to make them bootable... as well as including a boot-image... that may (or may not be) seen as a file.

Comment: So, creating just the image of the original DVD wasn't enough?

Comment: It depends on how the image was created.  If you simply copied the files... then no.  It's missing all the boot-code stuff.

Comment: I didn't just copy the files. I used Nero to create the .iso image of the Mac OSX DVD so I assume all the files are there on disk are within the image.

Comment: I do not believe there is any special copy-protection in the OSX DVD... (at least none that I am aware of) ... but regardless... it appears that Nero did a less than exact copy.  I can't tell you any more than that.